# Getting cookies in nextjs client side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, next.js13

I'm trying to check weather a specific cookie exist and delete some data from redux if it doesn't, but I'm not able to get the cookies even after using a package called 'cookies-next'.

I'm using client side component in order to mutate the state in redux. Anyone knows how to get cookies in client side with or without a package?

Answer (score 0):

**Using cookies-next package**

```
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
const cookieValue = getCookie('cookie_name');
```

**Without any package**

```
const cookieValue = document.cookie.split('; ')
  .find(row => row.startsWith('cookieName='))
  ?.split('=')[1];
```

You can access cookies using document.cookie.

Comment: It won't work because it's httpOnly cookie. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following below code :

```javascript
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
type RequestBody = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const body: RequestBody = await request.json();
  const value = {
    email: body.email,
    password: body.password,
  };
  const res = await fetch("https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "no-cache",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(value),
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  if (data.success) {
    // Then set a cookie
    const response = NextResponse.json(
      {
        success: data.success,
      },
      { status: 200 }
    );

    response.cookies.set({
      name: "login",
      value: "true",
      httpOnly: true,
    });
    response.cookies.set({
      name: "access_token",
      value: data.access_token, //token value here
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: data.expires_in,
    });
    return response;
  }
  return new NextResponse(null, {
    status: 404,
    statusText: "Bad request",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    },
  });
}
```

After in app/api/users/route.ts , you can get cookie

```javascript
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
type ResponseBody = { errors: { message: string }[] } | { username: string };
async function getUserByValidSessionToken(token : string){
  
    const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/user-profile',{
         headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Authorization":"Bearer "+token
         },
    });
   
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
      username: data.name
    }
}

export async function GET(
    request: NextRequest
  ): Promise<NextResponse<ResponseBody>> {
    const token = request.cookies.get("access_token");
    const user = !token?.value
      ? undefined
      : await getUserByValidSessionToken(token.value);
  
    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        errors: [{ message: "User not found by session token" }],
      });
    }
  
    return NextResponse.json({
      username: user.username,
    });
```

Example in the article you can see it:
[Check Login Using Middleware With NextJS 13](https://hoanguyenit.com/check-login-using-middleware-with-nextjs-13.html)